# how to tell browser to re- render replaced SVG content

Tags: jquery, svg

I have a SVG, so far so easy; imagine I want to have a thumbnail of this SVG on my page, too.

So whats a (fairly easy looking) way to achieve that:

```
$('#thumbnail').html($('#the-picture').html())
```

wher `thumbnail` and `the-picture` are SVG elements

the problem is, that the SVG engine does not (re-)render after the change of content. I am sure I have allready read the solution here on SO, but I cant find it any more!

annotation I: if a dup the 'html' of the svgs on server side it looks as pretty as I want

annotation II: DOMbroser shows me the correct content, but it is not displayed in the element

**edit**

I want to use my thumbnail as a lens for the main svg later

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your thumbnail to re-render when the main svg image is changed?

Comment: no - no change;  I want my thumbnail to have the same content as the main svg (just smaller) and this displayed, think about it that i dont want to send the svg data twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize an svg element by putting it into an image tag, and styling the image tag according to your requirements. No javascript required!

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate how I would do it. http://jsfiddle.net/A3v3c/1/

**html**

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">

<img class="main"  src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
```

**css**

```
.thumbnail{
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.main{
    width:500px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternately, if you dont want to request the data twice, you could do something like this:

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QWvKd/

**js**

```
var svg = $("#Layer_1");
var thumbnailWidth = svg.width() / 4;
var thumbnailHeight = svg.height() / 4;

 $("#Layer_1").clone().width(thumbnailWidth).height(thumbnailHeight).appendTo(".thumbnail");
```

**html**

```
<div class="main">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
     xml:space="preserve">
<ellipse fill="#C6C6C6" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
<path id="bird" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
    c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
    c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
    c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
    c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
    c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
    c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
    c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
    c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
    c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
    c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
    c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
    c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
    c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
    z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
    C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">

</div>
```

**css**

```
.thumbnail{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer; it does not fit to my prob. I want two SVGs and I do not want to transmit the data twice

Comment: this could be a solution, clone the content of a div and change it, not clone the svg (if i read your answer correctly), takes a bit to implement that

Comment: I was nice enough to write you code free of charge, you can do the rest.

Comment: does it. clone the svg interieur (inner)

Comment: $('#the-picture').clone().appendTo($('#lense-svg'))

Comment: i would remove the parts of the answer that referre to IMG / its missleading to the answer

Comment: The `<img>` method looks a better solution to me - the browser should only make one request for the same image as long as the server is set up correctly. Doing it all in js/jquery looks like an overcomplication. From an outsider's perspective ;)